# Turn on LED with EBlock Expansion FEZ Raptor

Tags: c#, led, gadgeteer

I have a project to my studies and I need your help to use the `EBlock Expansion`.
I need to make a test before I create the final program.

The test:
I have the `EBlock Expansion` with name `GPIO` in the image and plug in socket 18 on the mainboard Raptor and on the `EBlock Expansion` I have a LED plugged in PIN 9.
I need to turn the LED ON when I press the button (plug in socket 12).

How can I do this using Visual Studio 2013?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.
And sorry for my english, I'm french.
If you have any questions, I'm ready to elaborate.

Here is a picture of the conceptual layout:

[image]